# Flutter type 'loginModel' is not a subtype of type 'UserModel'

Tags: database, flutter, mobile, sqflite

There is an error because I am trying to use 2 different table models, 1.loginModel and 2. UserModel. In this code it is to push the data listed from setSP to the HomeForm but the userData is from loginModel and the data from setSP are from UserModel, the error happens because of that

```
    String uname = _conUserName.text;
    String passwd = _conPassword.text;

    if (uname.isEmpty) {
      alertDialog(context, "Please Enter Username");
    } else if (passwd.isEmpty) {
      alertDialog(context, "Please Enter Password");
    } else {
      await dbHelper.getLoginUser(uname, passwd).then((userData) {
        if (userData != null) {
          setSP(userData).whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeForm()),
                (Route<dynamic> route) => true);
          });
        } else {
          alertDialog(context, "Error: User Not Found");
        }
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
        alertDialog(context, "Error: Login Fail");
      });
    }
  }
```

```
  Future setSP(UserModel user) async {
    final SharedPreferences sp = await _pref;

    sp.setString("user_id", user.user_id);
    sp.setString("user_name", user.user_name);
    sp.setString("email", user.email);
    sp.setString("password", user.password);
    sp.setInt("phone", user.phone);
    sp.setString("role", user.role);
  }
```

Here is the function giving the data to userData,

```
  Future<loginModel> getLoginUser(String userId, String password) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $Table_login WHERE "
        "$C_UName = '$userId' AND "
        "$C_Password = '$password'");

    if (res.length > 0) {
      return loginModel.fromMap(res.first);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

In case the model files are needed,

```
class UserModel {
  String user_id;
  String user_name;
  String email;
  String password;
  int phone;
  String role;

  UserModel(this.user_id, this.user_name, this.email, this.password, this.phone,
      this.role);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': user_id,
      'username': user_name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'phone': phone,
      'role': role
    };
    return map;
  }

  UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    user_id = map['id'];
    user_name = map['username'];
    email = map['email'];
    password = map['password'];
    phone = map['password'];
    role = map['role'];
  }
}
```

```
class loginModel {
  String user_id;
  String user_name;
  String password;

  loginModel(this.user_id, this.user_name, this.password);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': user_id,
      'username': user_name,
      'password': password
    };
    return map;
  }

  loginModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    user_id = map['id'];
    user_name = map['username'];
    password = map['password'];
  }
}
```

I don't understand why this would be an issue since I think I gave where to get each data from, so can somebody help me with this please?

Edit 1: gave a better look for the first code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your method setSP wants argument with UserModel type, but you try to put there another type - loginModel. Your function for example needs to get user.email - but login doesn't have this field. Any way, you need to create userModel with fields from login and give another fields manually or make them nullable

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but is there a way to use those 2 types? because I need to use the login model for the login information while pushing the setSP method with the data from UserModel